# Spring Data Neo4j Repository Composition error: No property XXXX found for type YYYY

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

This should be a simple question about something that I'm probably missing from the Spring Data documentation.

I'm trying to implement a repository extension as described in: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#d0e2970.

The code is really simple. I just have a repository and an extension interface (and implementation).

First a repository for `MyType` class:

```
public interface MyTypeRepository extends 
        GraphRepository<MyType>, MyTypeRepositoryExtension { }
```

Then the extension interface:

```
public interface MyTypeRepositoryExtension {
    void anyMethodNameForQuery();
}
```

And its implementation:

```
public class MyTypeRepositoryExtensionImpl {

     public void anyMethodNameForQuery() {
          //custom query code
     }
 }
```

With this code, Spring Data throws an error while bootstrapping its mapping infrastructure:

`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property any found for type MyType!`

As what I'm understanding from this error, any method that is added to the extension interface Spring Data tries to map to a property of the respective type. But that is the only use of repository extensions? That is not what I was understanding from the documentation (linked above). If that is true what are the alternatives for custom queries?

A final observation is that I'm aware of `@Query` annotation, but my use case require a specific traversal and dynamic query composition.

---

EDIT: FURTHER INFORMATION

Looking at the documentation again I found some information that might be related to this. In order to configure repository composition it is necessary to change repository scan path from `org.example.repository` to `org.springframework.data.neo4j`. That is why any method that I put in the `MyTypeRepositoryExtension` interface Spring Data was trying to map to a `MyType` property.

I've set Spring Data Neo4j repository scan path as documented, but I've got many runtime class not found errors such as: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [javax/enterprise/inject/spi/Extension.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist"`.

In a try-and-error-totally-adhoc manner I have managed to find some dependencies that could fill out the missing classes. I've ended up with these dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-lucene4</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SP1</version>
    </dependency>
```

That eliminated the class not found errors, but now, since I changed the repository path, Spring is not able to inject the repositories.

The documentation tries to say something about this I think, but I couldn't understand what "put it behind" means in the phrase (from the documentation): *"If you use `<context:component-scan>` in your spring config, please make sure to put it behind `<neo4j:repositories>`, as the RepositoryFactoryBean adds new bean definitions for all the declared repositories, the context scan doesn't pick them up otherwise"*.

To sum up I really need some orientation here :-) ... Also, I think that the documentation needs to define the needed dependencies. And describe how extension repositories and standard repositories (interface only) can be mixed in a project.

Comment: Hi @pasemes! Any progress with this issue? I'm struggling exactly with the same problem (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724312/no-property-found-for-type-combining-repositories-spring-data-neo4j))? Have you got the right configuration? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know after one year probably the answer won't be useful for you, but maybe can help other people who is struggling with `spring-data-neo4j`, like myself these days (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29724312/no-property-found-for-type-combining-repositories-spring-data-neo4j/29807445#29807445))

Just point two things you need to change:

1) Following the `spring-data` repository naming conventions, the name of the implementation of your custom repository has to be `EntityRepsitoryImpl` (although the default sufix Impl can be changed by configuration). So, you need to change `MyTypeRepositoryExtensionImpl` for `MyTypeRepositoryImpl`

2) You don't need to change the `neo4j:repositories` package. `org.example.repository` is fine. **Don't** use `org.springframework.data.neo4j`

3) Concerning the dependencies needed, if you don't change the package repository as mentioned in the point 2, is enough with the basics:

> - org.springframework.data.spring-data-neo4j
> - javax.validation.validation-api
> - com.sun.jersey.jersey-client

I agree with you that `spring-data-neo4j` repository composition is a bit confusing and there are very few good examples online... So, finally I've decided to create a sample project on GitHub, with a basic example showing how we can do that.

Hope it help other people in the future.

See on `GitHub`: [neo4jCustomRepository](https://github.com/troig/neo4jCustomRepository)